# How can i use system() with rxrepl in WinCC OA?

Tags: windows, powershell, wincc-oa

I try to use:

```
string result;
string path = "C:/winccoa.projects/filters/bin/tools/rxrepl.exe";
string cmd = "'opcki' | " + path + " -s 'op' -r 'tata'";
system(cmd, result);
DebugN(result);
```

But in LogViewer i see nothing, instead ["tatacki"]

Why? What i doing wrong?

In PowerShell that works fine:

```
PS C:\> 'opcki' | C:/winccoa.projects/filters/bin/tools/rxrepl.exe -s "op" -r "tata"
tatacki
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that WinCC's `system()` function targets `cmd.exe`, not `powershell.exe` (which is typical, because historically `cmd.exe` has been the default shell, and APIs are unlikely to change, so as to maintain backward compatibility).

Therefore, formulate your command for `cmd.exe`:

```
string cmd = "echo opcki | " + path + " -s op -r tata";
```

Not the use of `echo` to produce output and the omission of single-quoting (`'...'`), which `cmd.exe` doesn't recognize.

If *embedded* quoting were needed, you'd have to use `` `" `` inside `"..."` PowerShell strings (or use `'...'` PowerShell strings (whose content is taken literally) and embed `"` chars. as-is).